# build-essential: no installation candidate *sometimes*

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I'm having a reoccurring issue when *sometimes* build-essential isn't available while trying to setup ubuntu 12.04.2 on AWS (using ubuntu provided ami: ami-ce7b6fba).

Script that sets up the instance:

```
set -o xtrace
set -e

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install build-essential
```

The fairly annoying bit is that it *sometimes* works. I have tried to add the eu-west-1 ubuntu mirror, but that didn't solve the issue.

Any ideas?

The output:

```
amazon-ebs: ++ set -e
amazon-ebs: ++ sudo apt-get update
amazon-ebs: Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg [198 B]
amazon-ebs: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg
amazon-ebs: Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release [49.6 kB]
amazon-ebs: Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg [198 B]
amazon-ebs: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release
amazon-ebs: Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release [49.6 kB]
amazon-ebs: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main amd64 Packages
amazon-ebs: Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main amd64 Packages [309 kB]
amazon-ebs: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted amd64 Packages
amazon-ebs: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe amd64 Packages
amazon-ebs: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse amd64 Packages
amazon-ebs: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages
amazon-ebs: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted i386 Packages
amazon-ebs: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages
amazon-ebs: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse i386 Packages
amazon-ebs: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex
amazon-ebs: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex
amazon-ebs: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted TranslationIndex
amazon-ebs: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex
amazon-ebs: Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted amd64 Packages [4627 B]
amazon-ebs: Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main amd64 Packages [677 kB]
amazon-ebs: Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe amd64 Packages [80.9 kB]
amazon-ebs: Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [2442 B]
amazon-ebs: Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main i386 Packages [325 kB]
amazon-ebs: Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted i386 Packages [4620 B]
amazon-ebs: Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe i386 Packages [84.1 kB]
amazon-ebs: Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [11.5 kB]
amazon-ebs: Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages [2633 B]
amazon-ebs: Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe amd64 Packages [211 kB]
amazon-ebs: Get:16 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex [74 B]
amazon-ebs: Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex [72 B]
amazon-ebs: Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [13.8 kB]
amazon-ebs: Get:19 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted TranslationIndex [72 B]
amazon-ebs: Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main i386 Packages [698 kB]
amazon-ebs: Get:21 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex [73 B]
amazon-ebs: Get:22 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en [149 kB]
amazon-ebs: Get:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages [11.4 kB]
amazon-ebs: Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe i386 Packages [215 kB]
amazon-ebs: Get:25 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en [1299 B]
amazon-ebs: Get:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [14.0 kB]
amazon-ebs: Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en
amazon-ebs: Get:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex [3564 B]
amazon-ebs: Get:28 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en [51.8 kB]
amazon-ebs: Get:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex [2605 B]
amazon-ebs: Get:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted TranslationIndex [2461 B]
amazon-ebs: Get:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex [2850 B]
amazon-ebs: Get:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en [726 kB]
amazon-ebs: Get:33 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en [93.4 kB]
amazon-ebs: Get:34 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en [2395 B]
amazon-ebs: Get:35 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en [3341 kB]
amazon-ebs: Get:36 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en [306 kB]
amazon-ebs: Get:37 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en [8064 B]
amazon-ebs: Get:38 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en [2637 B]
amazon-ebs: Get:39 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en [125 kB]
amazon-ebs: Fetched 7582 kB in 8s (930 kB/s)
amazon-ebs: Reading package lists... Done
amazon-ebs: ++ sudo apt-get -y install build-essential
amazon-ebs: Reading package lists... Done
amazon-ebs: Building dependency tree
amazon-ebs: Reading state information... Done
amazon-ebs: Package build-essential is not available, but is referred to by another package.
amazon-ebs: This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
amazon-ebs: is only available from another source
amazon-ebs:
amazon-ebs: E: Package 'build-essential' has no installation candidate
```

And when it works:

```
amazon-ebs: ++ set -e
amazon-ebs: ++ sudo apt-get update
amazon-ebs: Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg [198 B]
amazon-ebs: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg
amazon-ebs: Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release [49.6 kB]
amazon-ebs: Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg [198 B]
amazon-ebs: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release
amazon-ebs: Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release [49.6 kB]
amazon-ebs: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main amd64 Packages
amazon-ebs: Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main amd64 Packages [309 kB]
amazon-ebs: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted amd64 Packages
amazon-ebs: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe amd64 Packages
amazon-ebs: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse amd64 Packages
amazon-ebs: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages
amazon-ebs: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted i386 Packages
amazon-ebs: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages
amazon-ebs: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse i386 Packages
amazon-ebs: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex
amazon-ebs: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex
amazon-ebs: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted TranslationIndex
amazon-ebs: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex
amazon-ebs: Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main amd64 Packages [677 kB]
amazon-ebs: Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [11.5 kB]
amazon-ebs: Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe amd64 Packages [211 kB]
amazon-ebs: Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [13.8 kB]
amazon-ebs: Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main i386 Packages [698 kB]
amazon-ebs: Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted amd64 Packages [4627 B]
amazon-ebs: Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe amd64 Packages [80.9 kB]
amazon-ebs: Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [2442 B]
amazon-ebs: Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main i386 Packages [325 kB]
amazon-ebs: Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages [11.4 kB]
amazon-ebs: Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe i386 Packages [215 kB]
amazon-ebs: Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted i386 Packages [4620 B]
amazon-ebs: Get:18 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe i386 Packages [84.1 kB]
amazon-ebs: Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [14.0 kB]
amazon-ebs: Get:20 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages [2633 B]
amazon-ebs: Get:21 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex [74 B]
amazon-ebs: Get:22 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex [72 B]
amazon-ebs: Get:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex [3564 B]
amazon-ebs: Get:24 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted TranslationIndex [72 B]
amazon-ebs: Get:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex [2605 B]
amazon-ebs: Get:26 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex [73 B]
amazon-ebs: Get:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted TranslationIndex [2461 B]
amazon-ebs: Get:28 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en [149 kB]
amazon-ebs: Get:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex [2850 B]
amazon-ebs: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en
amazon-ebs: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en
amazon-ebs: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en
amazon-ebs: Get:30 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en [1299 B]
amazon-ebs: Hit http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en
amazon-ebs: Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en
amazon-ebs: Get:31 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en [51.8 kB]
amazon-ebs: Get:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en [306 kB]
amazon-ebs: Get:33 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en [8064 B]
amazon-ebs: Get:34 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en [2637 B]
amazon-ebs: Get:35 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en [125 kB]
amazon-ebs: Fetched 3420 kB in 2s (1637 kB/s)
amazon-ebs: Reading package lists... Done
amazon-ebs: ++ sudo apt-get -y install build-essential
amazon-ebs: Reading package lists... Done
amazon-ebs: Building dependency tree
amazon-ebs: Reading state information... Done
amazon-ebs: The following extra packages will be installed:
amazon-ebs: binutils cpp cpp-4.6 dpkg-dev
amazon-ebs: fakeroot g++ g++-4.6 gcc gcc-4.6
amazon-ebs: libalgorithm-diff-perl
amazon-ebs: libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl
amazon-ebs: libalgorithm-merge-perl libc-bin
amazon-ebs: libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6-dev
amazon-ebs: libdpkg-perl libgomp1 libmpc2
amazon-ebs: libmpfr4 libquadmath0
amazon-ebs: libstdc++6-4.6-dev linux-libc-dev
amazon-ebs: make manpages-dev
amazon-ebs: Suggested packages:
amazon-ebs: binutils-doc cpp-doc gcc-4.6-locales
amazon-ebs: debian-keyring g++-multilib
amazon-ebs: g++-4.6-multilib gcc-4.6-doc
amazon-ebs: libstdc++6-4.6-dbg gcc-multilib
amazon-ebs: autoconf automake1.9 libtool flex
amazon-ebs: bison gdb gcc-doc gcc-4.6-multilib
amazon-ebs: libmudflap0-4.6-dev libgcc1-dbg
amazon-ebs: libgomp1-dbg libquadmath0-dbg
amazon-ebs: libmudflap0-dbg binutils-gold
amazon-ebs: glibc-doc libstdc++6-4.6-doc
amazon-ebs: make-doc
amazon-ebs: The following NEW packages will be installed:
amazon-ebs: binutils build-essential cpp cpp-4.6
amazon-ebs: dpkg-dev fakeroot g++ g++-4.6 gcc
amazon-ebs: gcc-4.6 libalgorithm-diff-perl
amazon-ebs: libalgorithm-diff-xs-perl
amazon-ebs: libalgorithm-merge-perl libc-dev-bin
amazon-ebs: libc6-dev libdpkg-perl libgomp1
amazon-ebs: libmpc2 libmpfr4 libquadmath0
amazon-ebs: libstdc++6-4.6-dev linux-libc-dev
amazon-ebs: make manpages-dev
amazon-ebs: The following packages will be upgraded:
amazon-ebs: libc-bin libc6
amazon-ebs: 2 upgraded, 24 newly installed, 0 to remove and 76 not upgraded
```

When it doesn't work, `sudo wc -l /var/lib/dpkg/available` returns:

```
9280 /var/lib/dpkg/available
```

Comment: What is the size of your `/var/lib/dpkg/available` file on the two systems?  Or perhaps what is the number of lines in each.  `wc -l /var/lib/dpkg/available`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, figured it out.

```
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get update
apt-get install build-essential
```

Fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me on AWS & Ubuntu 18.04 LTS only twice `apt-get update` helped.

```
apt-get update
apt-get update
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).